# Meteor + Blade: Included templates still use the context of the parent

Tags: meteor, laravel-blade

When I include a template using `include "sub.blade"` the subtemplate uses the data context of the current template.

So, when I have the following:

**server.js**

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
    Template.root.valueA = function(){return "A";}
    Template.sub.valueB = function(){return "B";}

    Meteor.startup(function () {
        document.body.appendChild(Meteor.render(Template.root));
    }); 
}
```

**views/root.blade**

```
div=valueA
include "sub.blade"
```

**views/sub.blade**

```
div=valueB
```

I get an exception in template "sub" that `valueB` is not defined, because it searches in the context of template "root". So, if I define valueB on template "root", it works without problems.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is currently a bug in the Blade smart package. Thanks for letting me know about it. See [issue #103](https://github.com/bminer/node-blade/issues/103)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Blade that has since been resolved.

Comment: Thank your for solving it :)

Comment: No worries. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.